# How to get depth and channel for a cvMat?

Tags: opencv

I am convert a numpy array to a cvMat using fromArray() function. Now when I try to apply Threshold on it I get the below error
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats () in threshold

On checking on stackoverflow I see that it might be an issue with the channel or depth of my image. But I am not sure how can I check that for a cvMat. Could somebody tell me how to check the depth and number of channels for a cvMat in python.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't directly get it from a cvMat because cvMats have types instead of depth/channels, so

```
print mymat.type
```

returns the type code.
If you want to get the depth and channel number, the easiest way I've found is to generate the IplImage header with cv.GetImage like

```
print cv.GetImage(mymat).depth,cv.GetImage(mymat).nChannels
```

I believe cv2 does away with all of that IplImage/cvMat stuff and rolls it all into Mat though.

Comment: So then what is the cv2 way of getting the number of channels from an image?